# A UINavigationBar that hides using swipes leaves a region that intercepts taps to reveal it?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I've configured my UINavigationController to auto-hide it's UINavigationBar on swipes. Swiping up and down hides/reveals the bar just fine. However, a tap (touch) in the region of the screen previously occupied by the nav bar *also* triggers a nav bar reveal, and this is causing me problems. My view places a button near top of the screen. When the entire app expands up into the space left-over by the auto-hiding UINavigationBar, **taps on my button trigger the nav bar reveal** which is very annoying since I want swipes to reveal the bar not taps. I assume this is happening because the button has moved up into the space where the nav bar was.

Is there any way to prevent the bar reveal from happening when my button is tapped? I was wondering if I should override hitTest in UINavigationController to try to stop the event from propagating?

Here's how I'm hiding the nav bar:

```
let navVC = self.navigationController
navVC!.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
navVC!.hidesBarsOnTap = false
```

If I use RxSwift to subscribe to control events for the UINavigationController I see events like this:

```
received <_UIBarTapGestureRecognizer: 0x7b6dae30; state = Ended;
    cancelsTouchesInView = NO; view = <UILayoutContainerView 0x7b942bc0>; 
    targets= <("(action=_gestureRecognizedToggleVisibility:, 
        target=<UINavigationController 0x7da79400>)", "(action=eventHandler:, 
        target=<RxCocoa.GestureTarget 0x7b6e1f90>)")>>
    tapCategory=WhereNavigationBarWas
```

Comment: Can you share your code ?

Comment: Can you show us how you are hiding the nav bar?

Comment: @Gordonium I've updated the original question with the code and what I see once the nav bar is hidden and I tap on my button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it looks like there's nothing to be done with that UINavBar space other than to not let first responders move up there. I ended up moving my button to another location on the affected view and that sorted my issue out. My partner and I prefer the new layout which is a bonus. Thanks everyone!